# Qooxdoo - Theme to use is not available

Tags: qooxdoo

I have an qx v2.0.1 app working off the local file system and it runs fine in Firefox v14, but in Chrome v18 it gives me this error:

```
Uncaught Error: The theme to use is not available: edd.theme.Theme
qx.Class.define.members.initializeMeta.js:108
qx.Class.define.members.mainAbstractGui.js:82
qx.Class.define.members.baseObject.js:141
qx.Class.define.members.mainApplication.js:38
qx.Class.define.statics.readyBaseInit.js:77
qx.Class.define.members.dispatchEventDirect.js:134
wrappedFunctionInterface.js:451
qx.Class.define.members.dispatchEventManager.js:873
qx.Class.define.statics.fireEventRegistration.js:310
qx.Class.define.members.__fireReadyApplication.js:188
qx.Class.define.statics.onScriptLoadedApplication.js:106
qx.$$loader.signalStartupedd.js:159
qx.$$loader.initUrisedd.js:195
```

I thought I've come across this before and a ./generate.py distclean fixed it, but not this time. Someone else had a similar bug that was fixed:
http://bugzilla.qooxdoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1463

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you generate the app with `generate.py source` or `generate.py build`?! Do you get the same behavior in both of them?!

Comment: Hey @ThomasH, it only happens on the `generate.py source`

Comment: Did you get any error messages when generating ``source``, or warnings?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly enough, after a computer reboot it started working in chrome again.  So the chrome clear browser cache/history everything since the beginning of time must not catch everything. So now it's working again...odd.

Answer (score 0):

This question is too tricky, and probably involves things like looking at verbose generator output and your job configs, so it is not really suitable for a Q&A site. I suggest you open up a [bug for it](http://bugzilla.qooxdoo.org/) at the qooxdoo project.